# Secure/Non-secure browsing issue

Tags: javascript, https, facebook-apps, brightcove

I am developing a Facebook app that incorporates our Brightcove (video host) players and their API. Facebook gives users the option to browse securely and this poses a little bit of a problem. As is stands, I can get the app to work properly on one of the protocols (http or https), but not both.

https://www.facebook.com/atlantafalcons?sk=app_292392080815275 (change to http:// to see it not working)

If I set the BrightcoveExperiences.js file source to https://sadmin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js then it throws errors when someone is not browsing securely. If I set it to http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js then it throws errors when someone is browsing securely.

The documentation for embedding securely is here: http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/publishing-brightcove-player-https-page

Is there a way to detect if the user is browsing securely to be able to choose which JS file to load or is there a way to force users to browse securely? Or is there another workaround for a problem like this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Was able to come up with a solution (thanks to scibuff for recommending to check google analytics):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol ) ? "https://sadmin." : "http://admin.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + bJsHost + "brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

Comment: look at, for example, google analytics, or even facebook js sdk on how to add javascript to html with the correct protocol (http/https) - `document.location.protocol`

Comment: @scibuff thanks! was able to come up with something after checking google analytics. Edited original post.

Answer (score 2):

Use a scheme-relative URI:

```
//admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js
```

And don't use different hostnames for the SSL and non-SSL instances.

(Or have sadmin respond with a 301 redirect to admin for non-SSL requests)

Comment: I would recommend this approach.

Comment: This file is being hosted by our video host, not locally and the problem with doing this is that the subdomain changes in addition to the protocol.

Comment: `http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js` `https://sadmin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperience.js`

Comment: As @RGilkes has pointed out, this approach will not work as the domains are different for HTTPS and HTTP

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Quentin's suggestion. Although, using your suggestion, you can use:

```
// window, top, self, document, others?
window.location.protocol
```

In other words:

```
if (window.location.protocol == 'http:') {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'The page is using the http (non-secure) protocol.';
} else {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'The page is using the https (secure) protocol.';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3NREg/

Other window/document objects might work as well, depending on what you need:

```
// window, top, self, document, others?
if (self.location.protocol == 'http:') {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'The page is using the http (non-secure) protocol.';
} else {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'The page is using the https (secure) protocol.';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3NREg/1/